# PDF file or images for a book in android application

Tags: android

i am developing an android book selling application
the problem is that i don't know if i should use the books as a PDF file or as images.
reading of the books will be from inside the application.

Comment: You want to let user save the ebook on the device too?

Comment: As was pointed out on your last question... many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `.PDF` Extension for your Ebook.

Because Images tend to become pixelerated when zoomed to a certain level. Where as `PDF` preserves the vectors and does not reduce the quality of content (Images, text, etc) when zoomed.
Along with that, `PDF` is a wrapped collection of all the pages in a single file. Instead of many different image files for a single Ebook.

There are many Open Source Libraries for Rendering PDFs in Android
I have used [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android) Library for rendering `PDF Files` in my Android App.